# creating indexs

Tags: sql-server

I am working on index's, I'm still a little new at it.I am suppose to create an index on the existing Northwind view called “Products by Category” based on the columns CategoryName and ProductName. But I am running into a problem the Product by Category will not let me do it because of the by in there. There is a space in the name but the by gets highlighted.Is there anyway to get it to go away so I will stop receiving an error.

```
 CREATE INDEX IDX_categoryproducts
ON dbo.Products by catergory (CategoryName,ProductName)
```

Comment: The by is in the name of Products by category. the Category name is in the products by category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just noticed you are using `Northwind`. You would need to change the view definition to make it indexable as below.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Products by Category] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT Categories.CategoryID,
       Categories.CategoryName, 
       Products.ProductID,
       Products.ProductName, 
       Products.QuantityPerUnit, 
       Products.UnitsInStock, 
       Products.Discontinued
FROM dbo.Categories INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID
WHERE Products.Discontinued <> 1

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON [dbo].[Products by Category] (CategoryID, ProductID)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_categoryproducts ON dbo.[Products by Category] (CategoryName,ProductName)
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working cause I am trying to create an index on a view and the schema is not allowing it to do so. How can i correct the schema so it will allow me to create the index.

Comment: @sha - That is a different question. You need to ensure the view meets the requirements to be indexed. Is created `WITH SCHEMABINDING` and the first index you create needs to be unique clustered.

Comment: CREATE VIEW [Products by Category] WITH SCHEMABINDING ?

Comment: Thank you Martin I was working on the schembinding now I see what I was not putting in thanks again for the help.